# JSON from URL with Angular and django/python

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django

I got a file input and when I select a `xlsx` file it will be translated to json this works already the only thing is that I want to use the JSON with my Angular.

I got this:

app.js

```
.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}])

.service('fileUpload', ['$http',  function ($http, $scope, response) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(){

            angular.json = $scope.json = response.converterfile;
        })

        .error(function(){
            console.log("fail")
        });
    }
}])

.controller('ConverterCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload, response){

    $scope.uploadFile = function(){
        var file = $scope.myFile;
        console.log('file is ' );
        console.dir(file);
        var uploadUrl = 'converterfile/';
        fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);

    };

}])
```

I work with partials but that is irrelevant.

converter.html

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" file-model="myFile"/>
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="" ng-click="uploadFile()">upload me</a>


<div ng-controller="ConverterCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="json in csv">
            <td>{[ json.x ]} </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

backend is python

views.py

```
def converterfile(request):
    ''' Als de request methode POST is loop door onderstaande code heen'''
    if request.method == 'POST':           
        filehandle = request.FILES['file']
        sheet = filehandle.get_sheet()
        out = json.dumps( [ row for row in sheet.array ] )
        return HttpResponse(out)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("error")
```

so i want to get the json from the url with 
angular.json = $scope.json = response.converterfile;

but it says

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'converterfile' of undefined
> at app.js:76
> at angular.js:10296
> at angular.js:14792
> at r.$eval (angular.js:16052)
> at r.$digest (angular.js:15870)
> at r.$apply (angular.js:16160)
> at g (angular.js:10589)
> at T (angular.js:10787)
> at XMLHttpRequest.w.onload (angular.js:10728)
> ```

is there a way to get the json from fileuploadurl and let it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstoff don't confuse **front-end** errors with **back-end** code. If something happens in your **front-end**, the problem is in the **front-end** code.

The error: `Cannot read property 'converterfile' of undefined.`

This seems like an `undefined` error. Which basically means a variable is not defined. And in this case a property is called on something that is not defined.

(FYI, a property is an attribute like `name.property`).

So we need to search for the `converterfile` property. Because that's the property that is throwing the error.

```
.success(function(){
     angular.json = $scope.json = response.converterfile;
})
```

And there it is, the problem is that response is undefined. So to prevent this error, we need to add the `response` variable to the response function:

```
.success(function(response){
     angular.json = $scope.json = response.converterfile;
})
```